# libc6:amd64 current status 'half-install' POP-os

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running POP-os on my pc. Yesterday I ran `sudo apt upgrade` but got the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.32)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

so I ran sudo `apt --fix-broken install` and got

```
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so tried sudo `apt install libc6:amd64` and got the libc-bin error as before so tried `sudo apt install libc-bin` and got the following

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.32)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I feel like I'm going round in circles

Comment: have you had any luck with this so far?

Comment: @Ayyoub no. I ended up doing a fresh install. Looks like I might have be caused by an interrupted update.

Answer (score 19):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.33*
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb 
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-dev-bin_2.33-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb 
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

might have worked as it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep it in mind if it happens again.

Comment: Just a heads up in case people have different versions, mine was `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.32-0ubuntu3_i386.deb`. I recommend just tab completing for any files in that directory

Comment: This is the correct answer as it will directly solve the errors addressed, please mark it as correct!

Comment: I only needed the first and last of these commands. The middle two did not work but it didn't seem to matter.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

im new in stackoverflow, but i want to add to the responses that they are successfull and corrects answers, and they did work for me, in mi case i tried with this one:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.33*
```

but before i replace this part "libc6_2.33*" for this one "libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb", so finally y put in terminal::

```
 $ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb
```

and that work for me, because i search in the folder that directory and find that lib file, hope work for you! good luck